# How to Replace variable value in string python?

Tags: python

I working on python based project where formula's are stored in dB. My script will read the formula's from a particular column and stored in list .  For Eg

```
formula[0] = "round(float(latitude[:2]) + (float(latitude[2:]) / 60)"
formula[1] = "round(float(longitude[:3]) + float(longitude[3:]) / 60),6)"
formula[3] = "int(float(speed)*1.852)"
```

Through TCP socket comma separated values will be coming like

```
"imei:1234467454545,ac alarm,160302150105,,F,094605.000,A,1301.9905,N,08014.0746,E,0.19,298.01,,0,,,,;"
```

by coding I have split the comma-separated values and stored in list. From the stream `"1301.9905 "` is latitude, `"08014.0746"` is longitude and `"0.19"` is speed value.

How can I apply the value in the formulas and store in some variable? I have tried this method

```
latitude = "1301.9905"
latitude = round(float(latitude[:2]) + (float(latitude[2:]) / 60),6)
print latitude
```

Comment: Specifically, look at asteval, one of the answers in that post. It handles formulas very efficiently and safely.

Comment: If your socket produces newline-separated CSV rows, you could use the `csv` module to handle the splitting.

Answer (score -1):

you can store the formula in the as a python template and then use `eval` to execute it.

```
from string import Template

formula = "round((float($latitude) + float($latitude))/60)"
template = Template(formula)
out = template.substitute(latitude="1301.995")
eval(out)
```

here i am using `eval` method to execute the function.

for more info on `templates` check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

Comment: This won't *execute* the formula.

Comment: the `eval`at the end will

Comment: In many conditions, `eval` is considered evil. OP says the function string will be stored in the database, so it is possibly reachable by some other people too `eval`uating something without being sure what it could be is possibly dangerous

Comment: I'd strongly advice against using `eval()`; if there is any injection path to the database, you can get Python to execute arbitrary code this way. Use `asteval` instead.

Comment: Besides, if you are going to interpret the string as a Python expression, you may as well use `exec()` so you can just pass in `locals()` to use in the expression without any substitutions.

Comment: but the user requires this sort of functionality. also the user can add a sensitization step before passing it to the eval.

Comment: The highest voted answer in the duplicate question have many good examples of *how eval could be evil* . Using eval may look prettier and easier to use, but it have many side effects so any use should avoid using it if they are not 100% sure what will be evaluated. [This is better for explaination](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) . So it is not easy to make controls to check whether ou are evaluating something good or not. Use `literal_eval` instead